# Incorrect syntax near '@dni'

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

Estoy tratando de crear un procedimiento almacenado que realice un `INSERT` y ademas me cree un usuario.
El procedimiento en cuestión:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.nuevoGerente(@dni AS INT, @apellidos AS NVARCHAR(100), @nombres AS NVARCHAR(100))
AS BEGIN
    INSERT INTO datosComunes.personas (dni, apellidos, nombres, usuario) VALUES (@dni, @apellidos, @nombres, @dni);
    DECLARE @idPersona INT;
    SET @idPersona = (SELECT dni FROM datosComunes.personas WHERE (dni = @dni));
    CREATE USER @dni WITHOUT LOGIN;
END
```

El problema es que me arroja este error: "Incorrect syntax near '@dni'. Expecting ID or QUOTED_ID".
Estoy tratando de encontrar cual es el error pero por el momento no encuentro informacion sobre ello.

Comment: Estás intentando crear un usuario cuyo identificador sería un entero??

Comment: No necesariamente, en ese caso "@dni" es entero, pensé que quizás ese sea el problema, pero probé con "@apellidos" que es un string y obtengo el mismo error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No puedes usar variables para referirte directamente a nombres de BBDD, esquemas, tablas o columnas y probablemente tampoco para usuarios.

Entonces tendrás que utilizar SQL dinámico, es decir, construir la sentencía SQL y luego ejecutarla; en tu caso sustituir la línea con el `CREATE USER` por lo siguiente:

Además, como el mismo OP ha descubierto y comentado, no pueden existir usuarios que empiecen por un numero, por lo que hay que poner un carácter como prefijo a la varible `@dni`, quedando de la siguiente forma:

```
...


SET @sDni = 'F' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @dni);

DECLARE @consultaDinamica nvarchar(max) 
SET @consultaDinamica = N'CREATE USER ' + @sDni + ' WITHOUT LOGIN' 

EXEC sp_executesql @consultaDinamica

...
```

Comment: Funciona con mis variables de tipo string, pero con una entero no. He tratado con `SET @sDni = CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @dni)` y `CAST(@dni AS NVARCHAR)`, utilizando `@sDni` en `@consultaDinamica` pero solo me tira error "Incorrect syntax" a la hora de ejecutar el procedimiento

Comment: Puedes intentar trabajar de manera incremental, primero asignar a `@consultaDinamica` un ejemplo de la consulta que quieres ejecutar (inventando lo que iria en `@dni`) una vez te funciona, incorporas la variable. Puedes usar `PRINT @consultaDinamica` para que te indique que consulta intenta ejecutar en cada caso.

Comment: Probé dando valores específicos y seguí con el mismo problema. Llegué a la conclusión de que no se pueden definir usuarios cuyo nombre empiece con un numero. Por lo tanto lo solucione agregando una letra al dni: `SET @sDni = 'F' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @dni);`. De esta manera funciona correctamente.

Comment: Gracias @YuloVallejos, no lo sabia, amplio la respuesta por si alguien más llega aquí que tenga toda la información.